# Date format changes in php

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am passing a selected date on onclick event  to function,while passing the value date has been changed..
example,
selected date is: 2016-03-22

when it pass into function means its shows 1993

that is 2016-25=1993
can any one help me to change this

Comment: try to send the date in single inverted commas like '2016-03-22'

Comment: Update your question with what you tried (the code).

Comment: hey , i am passing a date in variable

Answer (score 0):

Assign date value into a variable and pass it as a parameter like

```
$dateVal = '2016-03-22';

echo $url = "http://utl.com?dateVal='".$dateVal."'" ;
```